# Is there a workaround for off-camera second-curtain sync with non-Canon flashes?

Tags: canon, flash, off-camera-flash, yongnuo, second-curtain

I have a Canon camera but only have Yongnuo flashes and triggers which won't allow me to use the rear-curtain sync camera function.

I've read around that there are *hacks* or *workarounds* to kind of simulate this function and even when I think they might not be perfect or a long term solution, I would like to try them just to test it out.

Does anybody know some usual tips or workarounds to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused by your question.  Wireless 2nd-curtain sync is not possible with Canon OEM gear; but *is* possible with Yongnuo flashes and radio triggers with a Canon body. If you use Yongnuo TTL/HSS-capable flashes and triggers, then you can do wireless 2nd-curtain sync.  If you use Canon's RT or optical slaving gear, you can't.

Comment: I understand. I'm talking about non TTL flash/triggers, that's why I was talking about off-camera flash. I'm almost sure that won't be possible with the actual camera function, but I thought there might be a way to get similar results with some other technique.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late to answer this at this point, but I'm going to anyway.

Depends on your setup, how many flashes, what models, what camera, etc.

I have 2 yongnou 600EX's myself and this will let you do off camera rear curtain sync. Rather than trying to tether the flashes together, or do something odd, I put one on the camera in ETTL or M (depending on your preference) and turn on rear curtain sync. The second flash is off camera and set to be an optical slave. The YN600EX has two optical slave modes, one for ETTL that ignores the pre-flash, and one that will just fire normally, so set it as appropriate to match the on-camera flash mode.

This should basically use the rear curtain sync of the on camera flash to trigger any additional flashes. That setup only uses 2, but you could add more quite simply. The one downside is that the flashes need line of sight. It would be great if there was a radio mode for this but there doesn't appear to be.

(Another option is to use your cameras built in pop-up flash as the trigger flash in place of having one on the camera. Again, depends on what camera model you specifically have, but many prosumer level bodies will let you adjust how the pop up flash fires, what power it uses, is it rear curtain or not, etc. I'd set it to more or less the lowest power so that it can trigger the other flashes but won't really affect your photo)